# msvcp100d.dll was not found -Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, dll

How could such error in image solved? I wanna to run .exe files but unfortunately I can't with such error!

[image]

Actually, I tried many solutions as download msvcp100d.dll but this does not work with me, also I tried to download  Microsoft Visual C++ as proposed solution for such error, but also this does not work with me!

**EDIT**
Thanks all my problem solved!! ,,,

Comment: I see such this solution BUT I do not know why still give me error really cause that I asked here ...

Comment: It is against the Visual Studio license to distribute applications compiled against the debug crt. Either install a licensed version of visual studio 2010 on the machine or use a release build which you can redistribute along with the visual studio 2010 redistributable package. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: actually I download it, but still give me such error! anyway thanks all ...

Comment: You can not download the dll or even the express version of visual studio. You need to do exactly what we are telling you.

Comment: I may be wrong about debug builds on Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Comment: Also remember the microsoft redistributables contain only release dlls.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is make a release build, that will link to the release version of CRT, which will be present in the target machines.
You can even static link the CRT if you doubt the CRT version you are linking against is absent in the target machine